# Atomic Writes to Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am using `Azure Table Storage` and I want to have atomic writes to multiple tables. Meaning that I want to have a transaction that writes an entity to two tables, and if one write fails, the transaction is rolled back.

I have been looking through the documentation and I see that there are transaction, but they seem to be for single table writes only.

> The Table service supports batch transactions on entities that are in the same table and belong to the same partition group

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/performing-entity-group-transactions)

Is there a way to achieve this for multiple table writes? Assuming that the `partitionKey` is the same?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve this for multiple table writes? Assuming
>   that the partitionKey is the same?

Out of the box, such functionality is not available. Entity batch transactions are applicable only for a single table. You can't use it for multiple tables.

What we have done in our application is implemented our own "`Eventual Consistency`" pattern. In our application, we have some data that needs to be written into multiple tables. What we do there is instead of writing that data directly into multiple tables, we write that in a queue as a message.

Then we have a background process which constantly polls this queue and picks up messages. Then this background process tries to write to different tables. The message is only deleted from the queue if we're able to write to all the tables.

When writing to a table, we take `idempotency` into consideration i.e. we assume that the data may be present in the table. Thus we always do `InsertOrReplace` (or `InsertOrMerge`) instead of `Insert`.